# proxy on linux like Microsoft ISA

Tags: linux, centos, proxy

I have installed jaxer server on my Linux machine and there is on program which fetch URLs if its local URL it works. But for external/public URL it does not work

I had this problem when I instilled jaxer on my Windows machine which was solved by installing Microsoft ISA and configuring it to proxy through that.

On Linux what I should do so that my proxy details are added to all requests I make?

Comment: ? What do you mean "down vote favorite"?

Answer (score 1):

Do you mean something like [Squid](http://www.squid-cache.org/) for Linux? You don't mention your distro but you might have it in a repository for easy installation if that's the case.

Comment: This might help. http://www.google.com/search?q=install+squid+centos